# conntrack -S - Can't open /proc interface

Tags: networking, docker

I'm trying to run `conntrack -S` to get some stats about NAT with docker.

But I get the error:

`conntrack v1.4.4 (conntrack-tools): Can't open /proc interfaces`

How can I go about getting statistics about NAT?

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```